# How do I make a struct generic over two types for information that is sometimes hidden?

Tags: generics, rust, types

I am making a multiplayer game, where the server has full knowledge of the game state (`Sure`), but the client only sees a part of it (`SometimesSure`, parts of the world are hidden, e.g. cards in a deck). I want to use the same `GameState` struct though and make it generic over those two cases:

```rs
enum SometimesSure<T> {
    Hidden,
    Visibile(T),
}

struct Sure<T>(T);

struct GameState {
    pub map_state: MapState,
    pub player_states: PlayerStates,
}
```

where `MapState` and `PlayerStates` should be on the client:

```rs
struct MapState {
    pub tiles: Vec<SometimesSure<u8>>,
}
struct PlayerStates {
    pub points: SometimesSure<bool>,
    pub name: SometimesSure<String>,
}
```

and on the server:

```rs
struct MapState {
    pub tiles: Vec<Sure<u8>>,
}
struct PlayerStates {
    pub points: Sure<bool>,
    pub name: Sure<String>,
}
```

How can I solve this with Generics or Associated Types?

Comment: I may be not understanding, but haven't you just described the solution with  `I want to use the same GameState struct though and make it generic over those two cases`? https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=70ceb850ad014a99e73a222ac476fa03

Comment: thanks, for your answer. What I want to do is abstract over Sure<T> vs SometimesSure<T>. Because let's imagine we add other fields to gamestate like here: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7b0e1647b9cc12d5928aab09ed3aaded then we would need to add more and more generic parameters. But there should be only one generic parameter that is either Sure<T> (serverside all fields) or SometimesSure<T> (clientside all fields)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally you would use higher kinded types here, but Rust does not support the concept. However, since [generic associated types](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/1598-generic_associated_types.html) (GATs) were recently stabilized, you can use a helper trait (`StateType` in the code below) with a generic associated type to fulfill the same purpose:

```
trait StateType {
    type Type<T>;
}

struct ClientStateType;

impl StateType for ClientStateType {
    type Type<T> = SometimesSure<T>;
}

struct ServerStateType;
impl StateType for ServerStateType {
    type Type<T> = Sure<T>;
}

struct MapState<S: StateType> {
    pub tiles: Vec<S::Type<u8>>,
}

struct GameState<S: StateType> {
    pub map_state: MapState<S>,
}
```

Comment: Thanks @EvilTalk, I knew this is a classic call for higher kinded types, but just could not figure out how to do this in Rust. Your solution helps me a lot!